# Consulta em uma tabela vazia

Tags: sql-server

Qual é o retorno de uma consulta em uma tabela vazia?

Exemplo, estou rodando este SQL Command:

```
select Value
  from AVL_AnalogInput1
 where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from AVL_AnalogInput1) .
```

Tabela `AVL_AnalogInput1`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado da consulta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha duvida é, que tipo de resultado está me retornando? Esta me retornando nulo? Ou simplesmente não está me retornando nada? Posso utilizar este resultado para verificar se a tabela está vazia?

Comment: acho que esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145879/check-whether-a-table-contains-rows-or-not-sql-server-2005) pode te ajudar

Comment: Note que sua tabela não está vazia, ela contém uma linha com valores NULL. O NULL tem um comportamento bastante específico, principalmente em comparações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulte @@rowcount para saber se retornou alguma linha na execução de SELECT.

```
-- código #1
SELECT Value
  from AVL_AnalogInput1
  where TimeStamp = (select max(TimeStamp) from AVL_AnalogInput1);

IF @@rowcount = 0
  PRINT 'nada a declarar';
```

Detalhes em [@@rowcount](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql).